# Retrieving value of element using HTMLAgility pack

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am using HTMLAgility pack to parse html and then using xpath retrieve a table column with a specific class.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("www.url.com");

foreach (HtmlNode row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("(//td[@class='titleColumn'])[2]"))
{
    Response.Write(row.InnerHtml + "<br />");
}
```

I retrieve the data and row.Innerhtml looks like this.

```
<a>Title</a> <span>Year</span><br />
```

I want to save the value of a and span element in separate string variables. Please help

Comment: `row.InnerText`.....?

Comment: @Aran Thats gives the string "Title Year". I want to save the two separate in string variables

Comment: Well then show us what the HTML looks like. We've got no idea what it is that you are trying to run against.

Comment: @Arran if u read. I said row returns "<a>Title</a> <span>Year</span><br />"

Comment: Then just select the <a>-tag first, and then the <span>-tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xpath expression selects the second `<td>` that has the class `titleColumn`. According to the node's inner html, this `<td>` hode has two child nodes: `<a>` and `<span>`. So you could easily find these nodes, and then put inner text (or inner html) into your `string` variables. See, this:

```
foreach (var row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("(//td[@class='titleColumn'])[2]"))
{
    var a = row.SelectSingleNode("a");
    var span = row.SelectSingleNode("span");

    Console.WriteLine(a.InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(span.InnerText);
}
```

will output:

```
Title
Year
```